# What is wrong with the syntax for this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly simple MySQL query:

```
(SELECT
    id
    , creation_date AS date
    , 'order' AS type
    FROM bus_orders
    WHERE 1
UNION ALL SELECT
    id
    , start_date AS date
    , 'contract start' AS type
    FROM bus_contracts
    WHERE 1
UNION ALL SELECT
    id
    , end_date AS date
    , 'contract end' AS type
    FROM bus_contracts
    WHERE 1
) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Running it however is giving me the syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UNION ALL SELECT id, start_date AS date, 'contract start' AS
>   type FROM bus_contr' at line 1

I'm sure it is something obvious, but I can't quite figure it out. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `WHERE 1` or change it to `WHERE 1=1`

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT  id , creation_date AS date , 'order' AS type
        FROM bus_orders
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id , start_date AS date , 'contract start' AS type
        FROM bus_contracts
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id , end_date AS date , 'contract end' AS type
        FROM bus_contracts
    ) x
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: The `1` does not need to be changed to `1=1`. The expression still equates to true. The rest of this example you wrote helped me fix mine however. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a leading `)` that needs to be deleted.